# Countable subset under irrational

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Argument: There exists a denumerable subset of the set of irrational numbers

---

My argument is that if you add a rational number to an irrational number it will still be an irrational number but you can count to it

ex: 1/n+sqrt(2) 
is this a vaild example?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Or, if you want to be fancy: $\,\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \cos(x) = 0\}\,$.

Comment: { pi + n : n in N}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid.

Alternatively, $\{\sqrt2 n: n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rational+irrational = irrational. This can be proven by noting that if there is a rational number r and irrational i such that s=r+i is rational, then s-r = i, which would mean that there are two rational numbers whose difference is irrational.

Comment: Ohh perfect thanks, is there i really liked how you showed the s-r=i

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a countable subset of the irrationals, with the additional property that its elements are independent over the rationals: Enumerate the primes, and take their square roots.